# Who is Jacques Riboud?

Tags: research, schools-of-thought

I have been thinking a lot about money from a philosophical perspective lately, and somehow I kind of obscurely came across a book title in a google search, [The Mechanics of Money by Jacques Riboud, 1980](https://books.google.dk/books?hl=da&lr=&id=31quCwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA3&dq=%22Jacques%20riboud%22&ots=1ETJXQ6dMP&sig=Hf_dFJwuU8-Ki6vlyIOi4Jcg9HQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Jacques%20riboud%22&f=false). I have only found a few other works by him. From what I have seen so far they look to be of scholarly and theoretical interest enough to read further. I have found no information about him, but the book linked above has a forward by [Fritz Machlup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Machlup), who it seems is a more well-known economist with some theoretical contributions.

I find Riboud’s books interesting and I was curious why he seems to have fallen into such obscurity; his books have almost no citations according to this: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-349-11821-2

I was just curious if history has forgotten him or if I just haven’t seen much about him on the internet.

Comment: It seems he is better known as an innovative property developer - see https://www.cairn-int.info/article-E_RHU_048_0095--jacques-riboud-militant-property.htm and https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Riboud (the latter is in French but a browser may translate).